# jQuery BubblePopup not displaying on modal dialog

Tags: jquery, user-interface, popup

I'm trying to put a bubblepopup inside a tab inside a modal dialog, all created with jquery ui.

The bubblepopup is this: http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_bubble_popup_v2/

I cant show much of the code, since its split among many templates, but here it goes (it all works, except the bubble):

--- modal:

```
<div id="report" title="Report">
</div>
<script>
$("#report").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 440,
    width: 350,
    modal: true});
$("#report").load('/section/1/');
</script>
```

--- tab section

```
<div id="section-1">
    <li><a href='/content_for_tab_1/'>Tab1</a></li>
</div>
<script>
    $("#section-1").tabs();
</script>
```

--- here is the content for tab 1:

```
<p class="help_link"><a href="javascript:get_help('help_participation','participation')">Help</a></p>
<script>
$("#help_{{k}}").CreateBubblePopup({position : 'right',
              align: 'center',
              distance: '10',
              width: '300',
              innerHtmlStyle: {
              color:'#000000', 
                    'text-align':'center'},
              tail: { align:'center', },
              themeName: 'bubble',
              themePath: 'media/image/'});
$("#help_{{k}}").SetBubblePopupInnerHtml('Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet');
</script>
```

Somehow, I cant make the bubblepopup to show inside the modal, only on other components of the page.
Is this a bug in bubblepopup + modal dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize this is an older post, but we just ran into the same issue and resolved it by setting the z-index of the Bubble Popup to something higher than the Dialog window:

```
$('.jquerybubblepopup').css('z-index','9999');
```

Use Firebug and track the HTML changes and you should see the popup being created, just behind the dialog.